# How to execute another function after async completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript, promise

I am making angularjs and typescript based application, where in constructor i am calling load function like,

```
private load(): angular.IPromise<void> {

    const progTokInit: string = 'initial';
    this.$scope.progress.start(progTokInit);

    return this.entityService
      .load(this.$scope.projectRevisionUid)
      .then(resp => { 
         //Doing foreach and sending employeeModel
         //  to get the financetype of the person
         resp.employeeRates.forEach(employeeModel => this.getFinanceType(employeeModel));

         this.refreshCostRate(...resp.employeeRates)
          .then(() => // Another Function )
          .then(() => // Yet Anothoer Function )
     })
}
```

Here i am in the need to fetch the financetype of a person for which if i send the cost center number, i will get the data so i have given like this in `getFinanceType()` function,

```
private getFinanceType (employeeModel:any) {
    this.costService.getFinanceType(employeeModel.person.cost_center.getValue()[0])
        .then((result) => {
          console.log('res ', result);
          employeeModel.financeType = result;
          return result;
        });
}
```

This above function is asychronous so there will be a maximum delay to get all the relevant data until then i need to wait to move to next step i.e, i need to call `this.refreshCostRate(...resp.employeeRates)` only if this current `getFinanceType ()` function finishes its task completely..

I have tried using **async/await** like,

```
private async getFinanceType (employeeModel:any) {
    await return this.costService.getFinanceType(employeeModel.person.cost_center.getValue()[0])
        .then((result) => {
          console.log('res ', result);
          employeeModel.financeType = result;
          return result;
        });
}
```

but nothing helps, the execution continues eventhough this data was not completed so i am unable to set the data of `employeeModel.financeType` at right time.

Please help me out in handling this situation of wait until this `getFinanceType()` finishes its job then after execute another function and yet another function..

Comment: in your getFinanceType function you are not returning after your await keyword?

Comment: @KobanDavis, It doesn't work with it i missed return in code, edited now.. But its wrong way of approach i hope, waiting for better solution..

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `getFinanceType` function to [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) the promise:

```
private getFinanceType (employeeModel:any) {
    var value = employeeModel.person.cost_center.getValue()[0]
    return this.costService.getFinanceType(value)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('res ', result);
        employeeModel.financeType = result;
        return result;
    });
}
```

Then chain from the returned promises:

```
private load(): angular.IPromise<void> {

    const progTokInit: string = 'initial';
    this.$scope.progress.start(progTokInit);

    return this.entityService
      .load(this.$scope.projectRevisionUid)
      .then(resp => { 
         //Doing foreach and sending employeeModel
         //  to get the financetype of the person
         var promiseArr = resp.employeeRates.map(_ => this.getFinanceType(_));
         promiseArr.push(resp);
         return $q.all(promiseArr);
      })
      .then(financeTypeArr) {
         var resp = financeTypeArr.pop();   
         return this.refreshCostRate(...resp.employeeRates)
          .then(() => // Another Function )
          .then(() => // Yet Anothoer Function )
     })
}
```

Use `$q.all` to wait for all the data to return from the server before going to the next step.